# EFCore LINQ to SQL query slow when using one query

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

When using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.4` in a Console application to retrieve data for XmlSerialization I'm finding that the following LINQ query is very slow and takes almost 7 minutes to complete:

```
var fullSubmission = context.CYP000
    .Include(p => p.CYP001)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.CYP002)
    .Include(p => p.CYP001)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.CYP101)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.CYP201)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.CYP202)
    .Single(x => x.SubmissionId == submissionId);

24/10/2018 14:50:37 - Retrieved full submission in 00:06:46.8583712
```

Whereas if I do this in two steps to get the equivalent result the total time is less than 30 seconds:

```
var submission = context.CYP000
    .Single(s => s.SubmissionId == submissionId);

var patients = context.CYP001
    .Include(p => p.CYP101)
        .ThenInclude(r => r.CYP201)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.CYP202)
    .Include(p => p.CYP002)
    .Where(p => p.SubmissionId == submissionId)
    .ToList();

submission.CYP001 = patients;

24/10/2018 14:43:29 - Retrieved submission in 00:00:01.1036359
24/10/2018 14:43:50 - Retrieved patients in 00:00:21.0496461
```

I haven't spotted any issues with my DbContext or classes and there is sufficient indexes in database so what is causing the slow execution?

This is the log when using a single LINQ query:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT TOP(2) [p].[SubmissionId], [p].[C000010], [p].[C000020], [p].[C000030], [p].[C000040], [p].[C000050], [p].[C000060]

      FROM [CYP000] AS [p]

      WHERE [p].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

      ORDER BY [p].[SubmissionId]

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (15ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p.CYP001].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001].[PatientId], [p.CYP001].[C001010], [p.CYP001].[C001020], [p.CYP001].[C001030], [p.CYP001].[C001040], [p.CYP001].[C001050], [p.CYP001].[C001060], [p.CYP001].[C001070], [p.CYP001].[C001080], [p.CYP001].[C001090], [p.CYP001].[C001100], [p.CYP001].[C001110], [p.CYP001].[C001120], [p.CYP001].[C001130], [p.CYP001].[C001140], [p.CYP001].[C001150], [p.CYP001].[C001160], [p.CYP001].[C001170], [p.CYP001].[C001180], [p.CYP001].[C001190], [p.CYP001].[C001200], [p.CYP001].[C001210], [p.CYP001].[C001220], [p.CYP001].[C001230], [p.CYP001].[C001240], [p.CYP001].[C001901]

      FROM [CYP001] AS [p.CYP001]

      INNER JOIN (

          SELECT TOP(1) [p0].[SubmissionId]

          FROM [CYP000] AS [p0]

          WHERE [p0].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

          ORDER BY [p0].[SubmissionId]

      ) AS [t] ON [p.CYP001].[SubmissionId] = [t].[SubmissionId]

      ORDER BY [t].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001].[PatientId]

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (14ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p.CYP001.CYP002].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001.CYP002].[PatientId], [p.CYP001.CYP002].[C002020], [p.CYP001.CYP002].[C002010], [p.CYP001.CYP002].[C002030], [p.CYP001.CYP002].[C002040], [p.CYP001.CYP002].[C002901]

      FROM [CYP002] AS [p.CYP001.CYP002]

      INNER JOIN (

          SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP0010].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP0010].[PatientId], [t0].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId0]

          FROM [CYP001] AS [p.CYP0010]

          INNER JOIN (

              SELECT TOP(1) [p1].[SubmissionId]

              FROM [CYP000] AS [p1]

              WHERE [p1].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

              ORDER BY [p1].[SubmissionId]

          ) AS [t0] ON [p.CYP0010].[SubmissionId] = [t0].[SubmissionId]

      ) AS [t1] ON ([p.CYP001.CYP002].[SubmissionId] = [t1].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP001.CYP002].[PatientId] = [t1].[PatientId])

      ORDER BY [t1].[SubmissionId0], [t1].[SubmissionId], [t1].[PatientId]

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (184ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p.CYP001.CYP101].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[ReferralId], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101010], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101020], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101030], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101040], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101050], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101060], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101070], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101080], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101090], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101901], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101902], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[C101912], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[PatientId]

      FROM [CYP101] AS [p.CYP001.CYP101]

      INNER JOIN (

          SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP0011].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP0011].[PatientId], [t2].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId0]

          FROM [CYP001] AS [p.CYP0011]

          INNER JOIN (

              SELECT TOP(1) [p2].[SubmissionId]

              FROM [CYP000] AS [p2]

              WHERE [p2].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

              ORDER BY [p2].[SubmissionId]

          ) AS [t2] ON [p.CYP0011].[SubmissionId] = [t2].[SubmissionId]

      ) AS [t3] ON ([p.CYP001.CYP101].[SubmissionId] = [t3].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP001.CYP101].[PatientId] = [t3].[PatientId])

      ORDER BY [t3].[SubmissionId0], [t3].[SubmissionId], [t3].[PatientId], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001.CYP101].[ReferralId]

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (151ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[ContactId], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201010], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201020], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201030], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201040], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201050], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201060], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201070], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201080], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201090], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201100], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201110], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201120], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201130], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201140], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201150], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201160], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201902], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201903], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201906], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201909], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[C201912], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[ReferralId]

      FROM [CYP201] AS [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201]

      INNER JOIN (

          SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP001.CYP1010].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001.CYP1010].[ReferralId], [t5].[SubmissionId0], [t5].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId1], [t5].[PatientId]

          FROM [CYP101] AS [p.CYP001.CYP1010]

          INNER JOIN (

              SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP0012].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP0012].[PatientId], [t4].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId0]

              FROM [CYP001] AS [p.CYP0012]

              INNER JOIN (

                  SELECT TOP(1) [p3].[SubmissionId]

                  FROM [CYP000] AS [p3]

                  WHERE [p3].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

                  ORDER BY [p3].[SubmissionId]

              ) AS [t4] ON [p.CYP0012].[SubmissionId] = [t4].[SubmissionId]

          ) AS [t5] ON ([p.CYP001.CYP1010].[SubmissionId] = [t5].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP001.CYP1010].[PatientId] = [t5].[PatientId])

      ) AS [t6] ON ([p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[SubmissionId] = [t6].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[ReferralId] = [t6].[ReferralId])

      ORDER BY [t6].[SubmissionId0], [t6].[SubmissionId1], [t6].[PatientId], [t6].[SubmissionId], [t6].[ReferralId], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201].[ContactId]

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (210ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[ContactActivityId], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202010], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202020], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202030], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202040], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202050], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202060], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202070], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202080], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202090], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202100], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202110], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202903], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202904], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[ContactId]

      FROM [CYP202] AS [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202]

      INNER JOIN (

          SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP2010].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP2010].[ContactId], [t9].[SubmissionId0], [t9].[SubmissionId1], [t9].[PatientId], [t9].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId2], [t9].[ReferralId]

          FROM [CYP201] AS [p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP2010]

          INNER JOIN (

              SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP001.CYP1011].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP001.CYP1011].[ReferralId], [t8].[SubmissionId0], [t8].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId1], [t8].[PatientId]

              FROM [CYP101] AS [p.CYP001.CYP1011]

              INNER JOIN (

                  SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP0013].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP0013].[PatientId], [t7].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId0]

                  FROM [CYP001] AS [p.CYP0013]

                  INNER JOIN (

                      SELECT TOP(1) [p4].[SubmissionId]

                      FROM [CYP000] AS [p4]

                      WHERE [p4].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

                      ORDER BY [p4].[SubmissionId]

                  ) AS [t7] ON [p.CYP0013].[SubmissionId] = [t7].[SubmissionId]

              ) AS [t8] ON ([p.CYP001.CYP1011].[SubmissionId] = [t8].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP001.CYP1011].[PatientId] = [t8].[PatientId])

          ) AS [t9] ON ([p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP2010].[SubmissionId] = [t9].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP2010].[ReferralId] = [t9].[ReferralId])

      ) AS [t10] ON ([p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[SubmissionId] = [t10].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP001.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[ContactId] = [t10].[ContactId])

      ORDER BY [t10].[SubmissionId0], [t10].[SubmissionId1], [t10].[PatientId], [t10].[SubmissionId2], [t10].[ReferralId], [t10].[SubmissionId], [t10].[ContactId]

24/10/2018 15:43:44 - Retrieved full submission in 00:06:50.1565598
```

This is the log when retrieving the data in 2 steps:

```
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[30000]

      No type was specified for the decimal column 'C000010' on entity type 'CYP000'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values using 'ForHasColumnType()'.

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]

      Entity Framework Core 2.1.4-rtm-31024 initialized 'AppDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None

24/10/2018 15:36:34 - Getting data

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (82ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT TOP(2) [s].[SubmissionId], [s].[C000010], [s].[C000020], [s].[C000030], [s].[C000040], [s].[C000050], [s].[C000060]

      FROM [CYP000] AS [s]

      WHERE [s].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

24/10/2018 15:36:35 - Retrieved submission in 00:00:00.8605259

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (17ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p].[SubmissionId], [p].[PatientId], [p].[C001010], [p].[C001020], [p].[C001030], [p].[C001040], [p].[C001050], [p].[C001060], [p].[C001070], [p].[C001080], [p].[C001090], [p].[C001100], [p].[C001110], [p].[C001120], [p].[C001130], [p].[C001140], [p].[C001150], [p].[C001160], [p].[C001170], [p].[C001180], [p].[C001190], [p].[C001200], [p].[C001210], [p].[C001220], [p].[C001230], [p].[C001240], [p].[C001901]

      FROM [CYP001] AS [p]

      WHERE [p].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

      ORDER BY [p].[SubmissionId], [p].[PatientId]

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (175ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p.CYP101].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP101].[ReferralId], [p.CYP101].[C101010], [p.CYP101].[C101020], [p.CYP101].[C101030], [p.CYP101].[C101040], [p.CYP101].[C101050], [p.CYP101].[C101060], [p.CYP101].[C101070], [p.CYP101].[C101080], [p.CYP101].[C101090], [p.CYP101].[C101901], [p.CYP101].[C101902], [p.CYP101].[C101912], [p.CYP101].[PatientId]

      FROM [CYP101] AS [p.CYP101]

      INNER JOIN (

          SELECT [p0].[SubmissionId], [p0].[PatientId]

          FROM [CYP001] AS [p0]

          WHERE [p0].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

      ) AS [t] ON ([p.CYP101].[SubmissionId] = [t].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP101].[PatientId] = [t].[PatientId])

      ORDER BY [t].[SubmissionId], [t].[PatientId], [p.CYP101].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP101].[ReferralId]

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (149ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p.CYP101.CYP201].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[ContactId], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201010], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201020], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201030], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201040], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201050], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201060], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201070], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201080], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201090], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201100], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201110], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201120], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201130], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201140], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201150], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201160], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201902], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201903], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201906], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201909], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[C201912], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[ReferralId]

      FROM [CYP201] AS [p.CYP101.CYP201]

      INNER JOIN (

          SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP1010].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP1010].[ReferralId], [t0].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId0], [t0].[PatientId]

          FROM [CYP101] AS [p.CYP1010]

          INNER JOIN (

              SELECT [p1].[SubmissionId], [p1].[PatientId]

              FROM [CYP001] AS [p1]

              WHERE [p1].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

          ) AS [t0] ON ([p.CYP1010].[SubmissionId] = [t0].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP1010].[PatientId] = [t0].[PatientId])

      ) AS [t1] ON ([p.CYP101.CYP201].[SubmissionId] = [t1].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP101.CYP201].[ReferralId] = [t1].[ReferralId])

      ORDER BY [t1].[SubmissionId0], [t1].[PatientId], [t1].[SubmissionId], [t1].[ReferralId], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP101.CYP201].[ContactId]

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (190ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[ContactActivityId], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202010], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202020], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202030], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202040], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202050], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202060], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202070], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202080], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202090], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202100], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202110], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202903], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[C202904], [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[ContactId]

      FROM [CYP202] AS [p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202]

      INNER JOIN (

          SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP101.CYP2010].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP101.CYP2010].[ContactId], [t3].[SubmissionId0], [t3].[PatientId], [t3].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId1], [t3].[ReferralId]

          FROM [CYP201] AS [p.CYP101.CYP2010]

          INNER JOIN (

              SELECT DISTINCT [p.CYP1011].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP1011].[ReferralId], [t2].[SubmissionId] AS [SubmissionId0], [t2].[PatientId]

              FROM [CYP101] AS [p.CYP1011]

              INNER JOIN (

                  SELECT [p2].[SubmissionId], [p2].[PatientId]

                  FROM [CYP001] AS [p2]

                  WHERE [p2].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

              ) AS [t2] ON ([p.CYP1011].[SubmissionId] = [t2].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP1011].[PatientId] = [t2].[PatientId])

          ) AS [t3] ON ([p.CYP101.CYP2010].[SubmissionId] = [t3].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP101.CYP2010].[ReferralId] = [t3].[ReferralId])

      ) AS [t4] ON ([p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[SubmissionId] = [t4].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP101.CYP201.CYP202].[ContactId] = [t4].[ContactId])

      ORDER BY [t4].[SubmissionId0], [t4].[PatientId], [t4].[SubmissionId1], [t4].[ReferralId], [t4].[SubmissionId], [t4].[ContactId]

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]

      Executed DbCommand (14ms) [Parameters=[@__submissionId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT [p.CYP002].[SubmissionId], [p.CYP002].[PatientId], [p.CYP002].[C002020], [p.CYP002].[C002010], [p.CYP002].[C002030], [p.CYP002].[C002040], [p.CYP002].[C002901]

      FROM [CYP002] AS [p.CYP002]

      INNER JOIN (

          SELECT [p3].[SubmissionId], [p3].[PatientId]

          FROM [CYP001] AS [p3]

          WHERE [p3].[SubmissionId] = @__submissionId_0

      ) AS [t5] ON ([p.CYP002].[SubmissionId] = [t5].[SubmissionId]) AND ([p.CYP002].[PatientId] = [t5].[PatientId])

      ORDER BY [t5].[SubmissionId], [t5].[PatientId]

24/10/2018 15:36:53 - Retrieved patients in 00:00:18.1113376
```

**Classes**

```
public class CYP000
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }

    // CYP000 Properties

    [XmlElement("CYP001")]
    public List<CYP001> CYP001 { get; set; }
}

public class CYP001
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public long PatientId { get; set; }

    // CYP001 Properties

    [XmlIgnore]
    public CYP000 CYP000 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CYP101")]
    public List<CYP101> CYP101 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CYP002")]
    public List<CYP002> CYP002 {get;set;}
}

public class CYP002
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public long PatientId { get; set; }

    // CYP002 Properties

    [XmlIgnore]
    public CYP001 CYP001 { get; set; }
}

public class CYP101
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public long ReferralId { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public long PatientId { get; set; }

    // CYP101 Properties

    [XmlIgnore]
    public CYP001 CYP001 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CYP201")]
    public List<CYP201> CYP201 { get; set; }
}

public class CYP201
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public long ContactId { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public long ReferralId { get; set; }

    // CYP201 Properties

    [XmlIgnore]
    public CYP101 CYP101 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CYP202")]
    public List<CYP202> CYP202 { get; set; }
}

public class CYP202
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public long ContactId { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public long ContactActivityId { get; set; }

    // CYP202 Properties

    [XmlIgnore]
    public CYP201 CYP201 { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public DbSet<CYP000> CYP000 { get; set; }
public DbSet<CYP001> CYP001 { get; set; }
public DbSet<CYP002> CYP002 { get; set; }
public DbSet<CYP101> CYP101 { get; set; }
public DbSet<CYP201> CYP201 { get; set; }
public DbSet<CYP202> CYP202 { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // CYP000
    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP000>()
        .HasKey(e => e.SubmissionId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP000>()
        .HasMany(e => e.CYP001)
        .WithOne(e => e.CYP000)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.SubmissionId)
        .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.SubmissionId);

    // CYP001
    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP001>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.SubmissionId, e.PatientId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP001>()
        .HasMany(e => e.CYP101)
        .WithOne(e => e.CYP001)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.SubmissionId, e.PatientId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP001>()
        .HasMany(e => e.CYP002)
        .WithOne(e => e.CYP001)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.SubmissionId, e.PatientId });

    // CYP002
    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP002>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.SubmissionId, e.PatientId, e.C002020 });


    // CYP101
    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP101>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.SubmissionId, e.ReferralId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP101>()
        .HasMany(e => e.CYP201)
        .WithOne(e => e.CYP101)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.SubmissionId, e.ReferralId });

    // CYP201
    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP201>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.SubmissionId, e.ContactId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP201>()
        .HasMany(e => e.CYP202)
        .WithOne(e => e.CYP201)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.SubmissionId, e.ContactId });

    // CYP202
    modelBuilder.Entity<CYP202>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.SubmissionId, e.ContactActivityId });
}
```

Comment: Curious why your not using  `AsNoTracking()` method because your linq function looks like a read operation.  ex `var fullSubmission = context.AsNoTracking().CYP000 ...`. This tells ef not to track the query. 
    .Include(p => p.CYP001)`

Comment: `AsNoTracking` is being set on my context once initialized which isn't shown in my code